# iOS: retrieve volume from different 'routes'

Tags: ios, audio

I want to save the current volume in my application, which is easily accessible by using the `[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]` and I can listen to different hardware 'routes' by subscribing to route change notifications (so I can detect headphones, etc).

However, I couldn't figure out how to do the following; get the volume of both the iOS device and the headphones at once. Right now, I can only retrieve the volume of the current active hardware route.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is enough of an answer, but by the best I could manage was to do as you say and retrieve the volume of the headphones when they are the active route. I then compare this to the volume prior.

To get the headphone volume when plugged in, you can subscribe to `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioRouteDidChange:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
```

And then comparing the current volume in the callback to a last recorded volume.

```
- (void) audioRouteDidChange:(NSNotification*)notificaiton {
    AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason routeChangeReason = [[notificaiton.userInfo valueForKey:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] intValue];        

    if (routeChangeReason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNewDeviceAvailable) {
        AVAudioSessionRouteDescription* route = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute];
        for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* desc in [route outputs]) {
            if ([[desc portType] isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones])
                [self saveHeadphoneVolume];
        }
    }
}
```

(This code will only work when headphones are plugged in after the app is started, but you could of course check the route and its volume before adding the notification observer.)